# Как дождаться ответа пользователя telegram python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, if

Это изменённый код.
Мне надо поставить условие в calculation_for_falling_asleep, которое будет ожидать сообщение от пользователя.

Я пробовал сделать похожее с bot.register_next_step_handler, но пока этот метод ждёт сообщение от пользователя, код продолжается.

Мой вопрос:
Мне нужно такое условие , при котором код не будет продолжаться пока не придёт сообщение от пользователя.

```
bool_calculation = True

def calculation_for_falling_asleep(message: types.Message):
    num_input = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "<i><b>Неверный формат</b></i>\n\n<b>Введите число ещё раз:</b>", parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup_Inline_Back)

    bot.register_next_step_handler(num_input, Check_msg) #!!!!!

    if #Здесь должно быть условие

        if bool_calculation == True:
            bot.register_next_step_handler(num_input, calculation_for_falling_asleep)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: А нельзя использовать инлайн клавиатуру?

Comment: Check_msg у Вас функция? Или это просто так написано?

Comment: @СёгунРайдэн да , в ней pass

Comment: @Utsiye К сожалению нет, инлайн здесь для другого(